# R: XLConnect does not pass variable names

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I would like to pass the results of a linear model calculation from R to a worksheet in Excel. For doing this I am using XLConnect with the following code:

```
x <- 1000:2000
y <- 3*x+rnorm(length(x))
fit <- lm(y~x-1)
result <- summary(fit)$coeff

print(result)

require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("/Users/andreas/test1.xls", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "test")
writeWorksheet(wb, result, sheet = "test", startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

However, the problem is that XLConnect does not pass the name of the coeffiecient(s) to Excel (here: x) although they are printed out correctly.

Does anybody has an idea about that issue?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Andy

Answer (score 5):

The variable name in this case ends up as a rowname once `result` is converted to a data frame. There is an argument called `rownames` in `writeWorksheet`:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("~/Desktop/test1.xls", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "test")
writeWorksheet(wb, result, sheet = "test", startRow = 1, startCol = 1,rownames = "var")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the names of the coefficient table separately to the values:

```
writeWorksheet(wb, colnames(result), sheet="test", startRow=1, startCol=2)
writeWorksheet(wb, rownames(result), sheet="test", startRow=2, startCol=1)
writeWorksheet(wb, result, sheet="test", startRow=2, startCol=2)
```

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi, thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, your solution does not work. If I do names(result) it returns NULL. Do you have an idea about that

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you were getting the table of coefficients from `summary`. I assumed you were just doing `coef(fit)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Although, I do not understand why you create nr and nc, if you do not use them later on.

Comment: Because the coffee has worn off. :) Edited (yet again).